# How show core user mail if node author not anonymous using Computed field

Tags: nodes, users, entities

I'am trying to set a computed field that:
1) show the core user email address if node author uid !=0;
2) and when the node author uid=0, no core user mail address can be find, so I show instead a node_email_field content that was filled by anonymous author during node creation

The following code is what I thought should be correct, but is not working. Thank you all for your support.

```
$uid = $entity-> uid;   // Grab the author of the node
if ($uid = 0) {   // Check if user is anonymous
$mail = $entity-> node_email_field [LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['email']; // Load email field content from node
}
else {
$user = user_load($uid);  // Load the user object, based on user id
$mail = $user-> mail;  // Load core user email
}
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $mail;
```